# How to use child_process in webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm trying to run command line functions in a directory while hosting a web application, but when I try to run the following code, it throws

> "Cannot resolve module 'child_process'":

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
```

It's running with Webpack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's running with webpack.

Do you mean its been bundled with webpack?

Either way, if you're trying to bundle the `child_process` module for use client-side, you won't be able to. It needs the Node Core in order to run since it spawns/forks a new process at the os level. Its not going to automagically spawn a WebWorker or some browser equivalent.

The above is true for the other Node Core API's, they just aren't portable as they exist, they're meant to be run server-side. [This github repo](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser) has a list of Node.js Core API's that have been ported to the browser.

Answer (score 10):

You have to make sure that `child_process` is not included in the bundle. Add it as an external, by adding the following to your `webpack.config.js` options:

```
  externals: [
    'child_process'
  ]
```