# npm replacement for fs module

Tags: node.js, npm

how can i find a replacement for fs?

i am using the itunes APN from npm (npm install apn) but it uses the fs module. I spend many hours on research and some suggested i had this to my webpack config

node: {
   'fs': empty
}

this prevents any errors but it obviously breaks the code so as far as i am concerned is not a solution at all.

I tried using fs-extra but this requires graceful-fs which in turns requires again the good old 'fs' module. So we are going in circles. How can i solve this please?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use `apn` inside a browser, which isn't going to work anyway.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhh, it all makes sense now, i get why they said to ignore fs. Thank you!!!! Can you maybe tell me how i can find a module that i need to build my itunes notification server backend?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use child\_process in webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741708/how-to-use-child-process-in-webpack)

Comment: @TheArchitect you can use `apn` in the backend if you like, but if you're trying to build a backend bundle, the issue may be that you're not setting the correct [target](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/)

Comment: Thank you both. Robert, can i pm you at all? I would be infinitely grateful for a few pointers.