# How do I utilize certificates/auth with web-grpc?

Tags: node.js, ssl, webpack, certificate, grpc

I am working with [grpc-web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web), essentially trying to port a working server side vanilla grpc/node example to the browser. My existing node client example connects to the grpc service like so.

```
var services = require('./my_services_grpc_pb'); 
var grpc = require('grpc');  

var secureClient = new services.MyServicesServiceClient(                                                                                                                                                           
    (host + ":" + port),                                                                                                                                                                                           
    grpc.credentials.createSsl(                                                                                                                                                                                    
        fs.readFileSync(certFile)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    )                                                                                                                                                                                                              
);
```

That seems to do what I want. However, when I try to include the line

```
var grpc = require('grpc');
```

And then bundle my code with webpack, I get an error "cannot resolve child_process". I did a bit of googling and found that child_process [does not work in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741708/how-to-use-child-process-in-webpack). I'm in a bit of a bind now, because the code examples that I saw on the [web-grpc-tutorial](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/blob/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/echo/tutorial.md) do not seem show how to establish a secure connection. They look like this

```
var echoService = new EchoServiceClient('http://localhost:8080');
```

How would I go about passing certs to the call/establishing a secure channel?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this issue? I am facing the same problem now...

Comment: @Zack did you find some solution for the issue?

Comment: No, I left the company and quit working on this project.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of using grpc-web with TLS here: https://github.com/salrashid123/grpc_web_with_gke. There's a section on how to use certs. You do not have to use GKE if you don't need to.

Comment: Finally getting back to this.. is there a way to "attach" the certs to the channel in the manner I have done in the server side example?

Comment: The client is not using a cert